# Is the phrase 'as to' always followed by a noun?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, to-infinitive

I was reading an article regarding idioms, and one of the contributors complained about the incorrect usage of grammar in professional writing. The exact topic isn't important, but something caught my eye:

> I can’t help wondering where those “professionals” learned English. If I’m wrong, would you be so kind **as to** straighten me out?

In the latter sentence, they use the phrase 'as to' followed by a to-infinitive. However, isn't the 'to' in 'as to' a preposition? Should it not be '**so as to** straighten'? My understanding is that 'as to' should always be followed by a noun, as it is a synonym of 'regarding' or 'concerning'. Here is an example:

> I asked many questions as to the state of the building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your examples are correct

**[...] be so kind as to [do something]** is a set phrase, but the construction is just like *so tall as (the Empire State Building/the BFG/your mom)*.

**as to [noun]** is a discourse marker, meaning roughly, "the topic of the following remark is [noun]". If you know Japanese, it's like は. You can [read about topic-comment structure here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment).

1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_and_comment

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't notice that 'so kind as to' is just 'so as to' with 'kind' in the middle.

Comment: @MJAda Do you know the construction "as X as Y"? This is a variation on that same construction. Just with "so" instead of the first "as". They're equivalent. It's like saying "To straighten me out, that would be very kind. Would you be as kind as that?"

Comment: That makes sense, and it does explain my confusion.